# Additional information in one API call

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk, fql.multiquery

Given below my code *outputs number of Posts, Likes, Comments, and Shares* for my Facebook page. It considers only present one week data. This is done using fql qpproach (I know fql is deprecated **but my code works fine** because the app I am using is an older app). I have few questions to ask and need help in getting that done:

1. I need help in converting this code using the latest api approach so that it can work on newly created apps.
2. The code outputs total number of likes, comments and shares just fine but is it possible to get the usernames of those who liked, commented and share the posts of my page in the past one week and update the values in a database table? If yes, how?
3. If point #2 is possible, can this be done in **one API call**?

Appreciate some assistance here.

```
<?php
require('config.php');
session_start();
?>

<?php 
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '012myappid210',
  'secret' => 'abc012myappsecret210cba',
  'cookie' => true, 
));

$token=$_SESSION['token'];

$pageid='88978302070'; //(my facebook page id)
$d=strtotime("now");
$d2=strtotime('now - 7 days');

$fqlAPIParams = array(
  'method' => 'fql.query',
  'query' =>' 
  SELECT  post_id,comments,message,likes,created_time,share_count
  FROM    stream
  WHERE   actor_id = '.$pageid.' AND
  source_id = '.$pageid.' AND created_time  <= '.$d.' AND created_time >= '.$d2.' 
  LIMIT 250' ,
  'access_token'=>$token
);

$result = $facebook->api($fqlAPIParams);
$postCount = 0;
$likescount=0;
$commentscount=0;
$sharescount=0;

foreach($result as $post) 
{
  $shares=$post['share_count'];
  $likes=$post['likes']['count'];
  $comments=$post['comments']['count'];
  $likescount+=$likes;
  $commentscount+=$comments;
  $sharescount+=$shares;
  $postCount++;
}

echo "Post " . $postCount . " Likes " . $likescount . " Comments " . $commentscount . " Shares " . $sharescount;

?>
```

Here is the output of the code you suggested:

```
Post: Likes: 25 Comments: 5 Shares: 30
Post: Likes: 0 Comments: 0 Shares:
Post: Likes: 25 Comments: 25 Shares: 54
```

PageID 88978302070 has 2 posts in the past 30 days (on 31st Oct and 21st Oct)

Few changes what I made:
1. I changed `'until'` to `'since'` `88978302070/posts?fields=likes,comments,shares&since=-30 days.` 
2. I changed the inner loop because one more issue I found was... instead of `$post['likes']` and `$post['comments']`, it should have been `$post['likes']['data']` and `$post['comments']['data']`

Code is working but Now the problem is:
1. It lists three posts whereas the page has only 2. One additional post is shown with 0 likes, 0 shares, 0 comments. Not sure where it is coming from.
2. Like count is incorrect. It only displays and lists a maximum of 25 likes and comments. I tried to put a limit of 999999 but it displays maximum 1000. Is there any solution to this? Actual like count for the two posts are 24483 
3. Comment count is incorrect. It has to be 90 but the code lists 25+5=30
4. It does not lists usernames of those who shared the posts.

Answer (score 1):

Without using FQL, you can do the following:

```
$d2 = strtotime( '- 7 days' );

$result = $facebook->api( $page_id . '/posts?fields=likes,comments,shares&until=' . $d2 );

foreach ( $result['data'] as $post ) {
  echo 'Post: ' . $post['id'] . ' Likes: ' . count( $post['likes']['data'] ) . ' Comments: ' . count( $post['comments']['data'] ) . ' Shares: ' . $post['shares']['count'] . '<br/>';
}
```

The above API result also includes the name and IDs for all the users who have liked / commented on each post. You can do another `foreach` loop in the code to cycle through the likes / comments and update your database accordingly.

Example:

```
// main loop to cycle through posts
foreach ( $result['data'] as $post ) {
  // inner loop to cycle through likes
  foreach ( $post['likes'] as $like ) {
    echo 'User: ' . $like['id'] . ' Name: ' . $like['name'];
    // code to check / update db here
  }
}
```

Running the above code for page 177526890164 (Narendra Modi) using `limit=2` returns the following. If you are seeing a blank page or an error, you're clearly doing something wrong:

[image]

The best way to test would be to make the API call, and then add `print_r( $result )` after to see if Facebook returns any data. If it's empty, there is something wrong with your API call.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Shah... When I ran the first code without a loop to clycle through post_id, it did not work and then I found out in the graph explorer that 'shares' field does not exist... instead its sharedposts still it did not work. Is it because the App is old? do i need to make a new app for this? May i request you to look into the issue and also if you can decode your example with a actual code with a realtime post id '0123456789' Thanks

Comment: The `shares` won't always be present in the data (where there are no shares) so you should always check to see if it exists first (e.g. isset( $post['shares'] ). You should do the same for likes and comments too.

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/bajaobiscoot/posts/300472446799955 Take an example of this. It has 27 likes, 2 comments and 3 shares. Also for the above code, I used Narendra Modi's page (page id = 177526890164) because it is one of the page that has lots and lots of likes, shares and comments still it did not work.... :(

Comment: Using the Facebook Graph Explorer (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=177526890164%2Fposts%3Ffields%3Dlikes%2Ccomments%2Cshares%26limit%3D2&version=v2.2) I see shares correctly. If you see `sharedposts` then modify your code accordingly.

Comment: I dont know what am I doing wrong but it just doesnt echo anything. It gives a blank page. Now I am looking at cadburydairymilkindia page (id = 104105339655077) and past 30 days posts. when i looked at the https://www.facebook.com/cadburydairymilkindia page, I saw there were two posts with total 201+225=426 likes, 25+7=32 comments and 17+6=23 shares. But when I try to get this count using the above code, it just doesn't echo anything. Can you please check this at your end and try to get the counts via the code? I request you to update your code in the answer so that I can have a look. thanks

Comment: What does `print_r( $result )` after the API call give you? Why don't you take the initiative and do some debugging for yourself to see what the issue could be? You are asking for help,  but not willing to try anything yourself.

Comment: Answer has been updated proving the code works. You're doing something wrong if you're seeing a blank page or no results.

Comment: I was responding after trying myself. Sorry for the inconvenience, actually it was a silly error, I ignored the underscore between page and id (page_id). Code is working but with new problems I have updated my original question for the problem. Appreciate if you can have a look at it.

Comment: Dear Mr.Shah, I request if you could spare some time to look at my updated question. Thank you.